# What is the difference between のに and には?

Tags: には

I came accross :

> 行くのに１時間かかる。
>
> 行くには１時間かかる。

And someone told me I could say :

> 行くのには１時間かかる。

So I would like to know the difference between all these in details please, thanks

Comment: Very curious about this one myself.

Comment: To me, 行くのには sounds more colloquial and less formal than 行くには. (← I think these two have the same meaning: 「行くのに + topical/contrastive は」)

Comment: @chocolate And in a sentence like 寝るには早すぎる, I don't think 寝るのに早すぎる is correct, so what about that ?

Comment: You're right, 寝るには早すぎる (or 寝るのには早すぎる) sounds fine, but 寝るのに早すぎる is a bit awkward. (Maybe it's because ~~すぎる needs to be used with には?)

Comment: @Chocolate If I may, what のに means precisely in Tchang question? Here it is said that の and に are in fact two separate words (japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57809/…), is that because it is another situation? But I feel the two situations are similar

Comment: @starckman の and に are separate words. The の is a nominalizer and the に is a case particle. (The のに here is different from one word のに meaning "although".) The のに in this question literally means の "doing" + に "for" → "for doing~~".

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: @Chocolate Is this similar to what I found here 彼は休憩中に音楽お聞く where に follows 中?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the same except for the contrasting nuance added by「は」

> - 行くのに1時間かかる
> - **行く**のには1時間かかる （**帰る**のには10分ですけど）
>     *Going* there takes an hour. (But *coming back* takes 10 minutes)

This one is sort of a "set phrase" where the は is playing more of a topic-identifying role rather than a contrasting one.

> - **行くには**1時間かかる
>     It takes an hour **to get there**

It seemed natural for me to switch up the word order in the English sentences there between using 行くのに and 行くには. Perhaps there is a shift in focus as well.

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure you would translate that way ?
I would translate 行くには１時間かかる by To get there, it takes 1 hour. Doesn't really matter but I just wanna make sure i'm not getting it wrong

Comment: I think both translations are good. The one I put in there was just the first thing that popped into my mind.